# Do I have to create Step definition folder for each feature file if I am using cypress-cucumber?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

If I have two scenarios like test.feature, test1.feature, Do I have to create folder for both feature files and include the step definition file in those folders?

Can't I include all the step definitions in one folder for all the feature files?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [“What topics can I ask about here?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read (the Stack Overflow question checklist)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922]. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

- cypress-cucumber-preprocessor library uses the concept of common and local steps. If you want to write duplicate steps for different feature files where their functionality can be different then you should use local steps. To create local steps you need to create a folder with the name feature file. However, this may lead to refactoring and moving the steps to global space(common) when the project will grow.
- [Cytorus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytorus): This is another cypress+cucumber framework where steps are only global scope